# Grab specific data using C++ with MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql, c, database

I am trying to grab specific information from a MySQL database in C++.
Lets assume I can connect and have my MySQL package working just fine.
The below picture is a database. I want to retrieve the name **LISA** and insert it into a variable to be used later. 
Anyone have any idea how to do so?
The below code works too.

DATABASE:

```
ID   NAME
1    Rico
2    John
6    Lisa
7    Max
```

This is my current output with the below code. I just want LISA and be able to place in a variable.

```
Input id: 6
name:
     6Lisa
```

CODE:

```
string id_query;
string outstr;
string str8 = "Select * From users WHERE id=";
cout << "Input id: ";
cin >> id_query;
outstr = str8.c_str() + id_query;

if (mysql_query(conn, outstr.c_str()))
   {
   cerr << mysql_error(conn) << endl;
   cout << "Press any key to continue. . . ";
   cin.get();
   exit(1);
   }

res = mysql_use_result(conn);
cout << "name: " << endl;
while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) != NULL)
cout << "\t" << row [0] << row[1] << endl;
cin.get();
```

Comment: row[1] contains 'Lisa', could you use that?

Comment: First, try selecting just the NAME column, `SELECT NAME....`. Second, is something preventing you from storing the result in a std::string? I.e. `std::string name = row[0];` ? Lastly, if you want the name on the same line as `name:` remove the `endl` from that insertion chain.

Comment: @WhozCraigWell While I was reading your comment I think I thought of a way to do it. I'm thinking to just output row[1]. Do you think that would be ideal?

Comment: @nemasu if I am doing a query on the id number how would I know the name?